# How to exec method based on variable name (EG: $this->$variable)

Tags: php

Been trying to figure it out:

```
$utils = $this->load( 'helper', 'Utils' );
$action = $utils->getAction() . '()';
$this->${action};
} 
public function Name() { .... }
```

`$action` is supposed to be `$_GET` or `$_POST` value of action key.

How can I load the method `$action` using `$this->$action()`?

Thanks!

Comment: `$action = $_GET['action']; $this->$action();`?

Comment: You call it without $ sign.  Just $this->action ()

Comment: @Supericy, using the Helper it gives me `Cannot convert object to string`, I'd like to use the helper since I have to get many arguments from $_POST or $_GET and that way I don't rewrite same code.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Error log: [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: CT_Menu::$utils in /home/jorgee/www/menu/controller/CT_Menu.php on line 12
[Mon Jan 07 01:53:57 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAction() on a non-object in /home/jorgee/www/menu/controller/CT_Menu.php on line 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to append the `()` to the string, but add them to the call.

Like so:

```
$utils = $this->load( 'helper', 'Utils' );
$action = $utils->getAction();
$this->$action();
```

They're called "Variable Functions" - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: Excelent, thanks! Wheres the man for that? I didn't even know what to search.

Answer (score 1):

If it can be $_GET *or* $_POST, then you can use $_REQUEST.

So in your case it would be something like:

```
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
$this->$action();
```

But the solution to the code you provided is just to do:

```
$utils = $this->load( 'helper', 'Utils' );
$action = $utils->getAction();
$this->$action();
```